# WCF HTTP Activation using Srmp TransferProtocol

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

I've got a windows service calling a WCF web service using netMsmqBinding with the queueTransferProtocol set to Srmp.

All of this works great, except for when the application pool hosting the web service gets restarted or recycled.

The only way to get messages to send is by manually browsing to the URL, or using some http ping utility.  Once the URL is activated the WCF web service starts to consume the incoming queue.

I had this problem before switching to Srmp, and I resolved it by installing the WCF Activation feature on the web server and naming the queue appropriately.

I've been forced to use Srmp due to firewall restrictions so port 80 or 443 are my only options.

There is a workaround here where I could set up a scheduled task to call each web service on schedule, but I would prefer a simpler more robust solution.

A full solution would be really nice, but I'm open to considering some other workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

OK found the solution to this and was sure that I tried it before.

Install AppFabric 1.1 and set the web service application to auto start.

This resolved the problem.